# php error passing to google map api for coordinates of address

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am getting the following error

```
    Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxx/index.php on line 22
```

When I am using this code:

```
    $lon = $_GET['lon'];
    $lat = $_GET['lat'];
    $address = $_GET['address'];
    $range = $_GET['range'];

    if($address != 'false') {
      $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address); // replace all the white space with         "+" sign to match with google search pattern
      $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=$address";
      $response = file_get_contents($url);
      $json = json_decode($response,TRUE); //generate array object from the response from the web

      //these are the latitude and longitude definitions
      $lat = $response->results->geometry->location->lat;
      $lon = $response->results->geometry->location->lng;
    }
```

I am admitidly unfamiliar with php. can anyone give me some pointers with this?
Thanks for the help

**EDIT (to show full code):
           Made by Daniel K. Schneider, TECFA Jan 2010. This is freeware
             Will connect to a MySQL database, execute an SQL statement and
             then return the result as valid XML. 
           */
          error_reporting(E_ALL);

```
      // ---------------------------  Configuration section
      $lon = $_GET['lon'];
      $lat = $_GET['lat'];
      $address = $_GET['address'];
      $range = $_GET['range'];

      if($address != 'false') {
        $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address); // replace all the white space with           "+" sign to match with google search pattern
        $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=$address";
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $json = json_decode($response); //generate array object from the response from the web

        //these are the latitude and longitude definitions
        $lat = $json->results->geometry->location->lat;
        $lon = $json->results->geometry->location->lng;
      }
      // Fill in according to your db settings (example is for a local and locked "play" WAMP server)
      // Make sure to keep the ; and the ""
      $host       = "x";
      $user       = "x";
      $pass       = "x";
      $database   = "x";

      // Replace by a query that matches your database
      $SQL_query =
      "SELECT 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(('".$lat."' -abs(lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) +           COS('".$lat."' * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(lat) *pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(('".$lon."' - `long`) *pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))as distance FROM wp_places_locator dest having distance < '".$range."' ORDER BY distance limit 10;";

      // Optional: add the name of XSLT file.
      // $xslt_file = "mysql-result.xsl"; 

      // -------------------------- no changes needed below

      $DB_link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Could not find or access the database.");
      mysql_select_db($database, $DB_link) or die ("Could not find or access the database.");
      $result = mysql_query($SQL_query, $DB_link) or die ("Data not found. Your SQL           query didn't work... ");

      // we produce XML
      header("Content-type: text/xml");
      $XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
      //if ($xslt_file) $XML .= "<?xml-stylesheet href=\"$xslt_file\" type=\"text/xsl\"  
      // root node
      $XML .= "<result>\n";
      // rows
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {    
        $XML .= "\t<row>\n"; 
        $i = 0;
        // cells
        foreach ($row as $cell) {
          // Escaping illegal characters - not tested actually ;)
          $cell = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $cell);
          $cell = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $cell);
          $cell = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $cell);
          $cell = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $cell);
          $col_name = mysql_field_name($result,$i);
          // creates the "<tag>contents</tag>" representing the column
          $XML .= "\t\t<" . $col_name . ">" . $cell . "</" . $col_name . ">\n";
          $i++;
        }
        $XML .= "\t</row>\n"; 
       }
      $XML .= "</result>\n";

      // output the whole XML string
      echo $XML;
      ?>
```

Comment: what is $response in your code? shouldn't this be $json?

Comment: the code was taken from here: http://colinyeoh.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/simple-php-function-to-get-coordinates-from-address-through-google-services/

Comment: the return there is $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] for latitude and $json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'] for logitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you encoded your json as an associative array (you passed true as second parameter) and you are trying to access it as an object using another variable name, so either remove your second parameter

```
//$json = json_decode($response,TRUE); //generate array object from the response from the web
//Don't pass true as second parameter
$json = json_decode($response);
```

And use the correct object variable

```
$lat = $json->results->geometry->location->lat;
$lon = $json->results->geometry->location->lng;
```

Comment: I did this fix and it removed one of the sets of errors, however am still getting 3 identical errors on each of the two lines $lat = x; and $lon = x; I am going to edit my post to show my full code to this point

Comment: You probably might need to add a level `$lat = $json->results->0->geometry->location->lat;`